# Where should I put `hciconfig hci0 up` for start up

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to enable bluetooth device when system is up.

Which is the recommended way to do it?

The command is `sudo hciconfig hci0 up`.

Should I put it in `/etc/rc.local`? or should I use `update-rc.d`?

If there is no "proper" way to do it, I'll choose the way with `/etc/rc.local`.

Thanks.

#### Edit

Following @krt's answer I added @reboot cronjob, but `hci0` are still down when rebooting. According to `/var/log/syslog` the job is running correctly.

```
1136 May 24 11:17:20 klein /usr/sbin/cron[2107]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
1137 May 24 11:17:20 klein /usr/sbin/cron[2108]: (CRON) STARTUP (fork ok)
1138 May 24 11:17:20 klein /usr/sbin/cron[2108]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
```

Comment: What (Linux?) distribution are you running? If it's Debian/Raspbian, what's the output of `dpkg -S /sbin/init`?

Answer (score 2):

Is your system starting `bluetoothd` at boot? If yes, then you should check its configuration: it might be overriding the settings you make with `hciconfig` as it starts up.

For example, the `[Policy]` section of my `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` has an `AutoEnable` setting, which defaults to `false`. If you set it to `true`, then all Bluetooth interfaces get activated automatically by `bluetoothd`.

If you want more fine-grained control than that, you may have to use `bluetoothctl` or some other command (depends on your BlueZ version).

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

with [systemd unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html), create for example `/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth-audio.service` and add `After=bluetooth.target`, in order to make the unit start right after `bluetooth.target` had been reached and `BindsTo=bluetooth.target` to make it fail when `bluetooth.target` had failed:

```
#!/bin/sh
[Unit]
Description=Bluetooth Audio Connect
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth
After=bluetooth.target
BindsTo=bluetooth.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/scripts/bluetooth_connect.sh
Type=simple
```

`systemctl daemon-reload` and `systemctl start bluetooth-audio.service` bring the unit up. the problem is, that running scripts from `udev` is pretty useless, while there is no bluetooth yet. here are the corresponding (my) [bluetooth_connect](https://github.com/syslogic/bash-scripts/blob/master/bluetooth_connect.sh) and [bluetooth_disconnect](https://github.com/syslogic/bash-scripts/blob/master/bluetooth_disconnect.sh) shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and used systemd.service to load up my hciconfig script at startup.

1. Save the script under /usr/bin/

   ```
    sudo cat /usr/bin/hciconfig_bt.sh
    #! /bin/bash

    # 'Interference between Headphones and Mouse' fix

    # from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth#Interference_between_Headphones_and_Mouse

    hciconfig hci0 lm ACCEPT,MASTER

    hciconfig hci0 lp HOLD,SNIFF,PARK`
   ```
2. Create systemd.service unit and moved it under /etc/systemd/system/

> ```
> cat /etc/systemd/system/hciconfig_bt.service
> [Unit]
> Description=Bluetooth Mouse & Headphone Interference Fix systemd service.
>
> [Service]
> Type=forking
> ExecStart=/bin/bash /usr/bin/hciconfig_bt.sh
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

3. Make sure that you do `chmod +x` on your script and systemd.service unit.
4. Run `systemctl start 'your systemd.service unit'` to make sure it runs successfully.
5. Lastly, run `systemctl enable 'your systemd.service unit'` to have unit to be invoked at startup.

If you are not familiar with systemd.service, check below articles first.

https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `/etc/rc.local` or `update-rc-d` you colud simply create a new `@reboot` cronjob. To do this, open up root's crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

And add the following to it:

```
@reboot hciconfig hci0 up
```

Crontabs `@reboot` runs the job *once* on each boot and reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sorry for late reply. I couldn't take time for raspberry pi. I did what you recommended but `@reboot` job didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Put the following in `/etc/cron.d/<yourfilename>`

```
#enable BT
@reboot root hciconfig hci0 up
```